# Adding a base entity for three different entities

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have this scenario where I have three entities `Book, Review, comment` and have the following tables:

1. Books `(Id, ReviewCounts)`
2. BookTranslations `(BookId, LanguageId, IsDefault, Title, Description)`
3. Reviews `(Id, BookId, CommentCounts)`
4. ReviewTranslations `(ReviewId, LanguageId, IsDefault, Content)`
5. Comments `(Id, ReviewId, Content)`

Now, I want to add two other entities to the design, `Vote` and `Report`. The vote entity represent a vote the user do on all of the previous three entities, `Book, Comment, Review`. And the report, where the user should be able to report fake `Book`s, inaccurate `Review`s, hate and illegal `Comment`s and fake `User` profiles.
The problem is, I need now to add three tables for the vote `BookVotes`,`CommentVotes`, and `ReviewVotes`. And four different tables for the report `UserProfileReports`, `BookReports`, `ReviewReports`, `CommentReports`.

---

Now, I think about adding one base table so to speak, called `Entities`, and another table `EntityTypes`, where `EntityTypes` contains data like "Book,Review,Comment". And the same primary key will be in `Entity` and `Review` or `Entity` and `Book` and so on. This way I will solve the vote issue, but not the report because the user can report a user profile which is a `User` entity. It doesn't make any sense to add the `User` entity to the list of the three aforementioned entities and "derive" it from the `Entities` "base" table too.
To be honest, I don't think the usage of one "base" table `Entities` make sense either, because conceptually the book, review, and comment are three totally different entities.

So, **my question** is, should or shouldn't I go with the "base" table solution, and if so, how should I solve the report problem?

Comment: Base entity leads naturally into classes and subclasses.  That leads into class table inheritance.

Comment: @WalterMitty So in other words, if the entities are not conceptually related in an inheritance relation, we should not use a base entity, right?

Comment: That's not exactly what I was trying to say.  But you can look at it that way if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NOT go with the single "base" table idea.   Since a single vote can only be about either a book or a comment or a review, but not about multiple items, it makes more sense to me to keep them in separate tables. Same for reports.

Databases with lots of small tables tend to perform better than databases with just a few big tables, so unless there's a modelling reason to combine the entities, I wouldn't do it.